# error: no matching function for call to 'MH_CreateHookApi'

Tags: clang, clang++

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <MinHook.h>
//Hook MessageBoxA
typedef int(WINAPI* MessageBoxA_t)(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT);
int WINAPI MessageBoxA(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCSTR lpCaption, UINT uType)
{
    printf("Hooked\n");
    return ((MessageBoxA_t)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("user32.dll"), "MessageBoxA"))(hWnd, "Hooked", lpCaption, uType);
}
DWORD WINAPI ThreadAttach(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    if (MH_Initialize() != MH_OK)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    //Hook MessageBoxA
    MH_CreateHookApi(L"user32.dll", "MessageBoxA", &MessageBoxA, NULL);
    
    return 0;
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if (ul_reason_for_call == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        AllocConsole();
        freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hModule);
        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, ThreadAttach, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

clang++ -m32 -shared -o Hook.dll main.cpp -LC:\msys64\clang32\lib -lMinHook

no matching function for call to 'MH_CreateHookApi'

Please help me someone.